# How to set process.env before a browserified script is run?

Tags: node.js, browserify

The initial `html` comes from the back-end. The server has a defined `process.env.NODE_ENV` (as well as other environment variables). The browserified code is **built once** and **runs on multiple environments** (`staging`, `production`, etc.), so it isn't possible to inline the environment variables into the browserified script (via `envify` for example). I'd like to be able to write out the environment variables in the rendered html and for browserified code to use those variables. Is that possible?

Here's how I imagine that being done:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>window.process = {env: {NODE_ENV: 'production'}};</script>
    <script src="/build/browserified_app.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12):

Instead of hardcoding enviroment variables here and there, use the [envify](http://npm.im/envify) plugin.

```
npm install envify
```

This plugin automatically modifies the `process.env.VARIABLE_HERE` with what you passed as an argument to envify.

For example:

```
browserify index.js -t [ envify --DEBUG app:* --NODE_ENV production --FOO bar ] > bundle.js
```

In your application `process.env.DEBUG` will be replaced by `app:*`, `process.env.NODE_ENV` will be replaced by `production` and so on. This is a clean && elegant way in my opinion to deal with this.

Comment: "so it isn't possible to inline the environment variables into the browserified script (via envify for example)" - asker

Answer (score 2):

You can change your entry point file, which would basically to do such setup and then require the original main file.

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';
require('app.js');
```

Other way (imo much cleaner) is to use transform like [envify](https://github.com/hughsk/envify) which replaces your NODE_ENV in the code with the string value directly.

#### Option 1

I think your approach should generally work, but I would't write directly to `process.env` since I am pretty much sure that it gets overwritten in the bundle. Instead you can make global variable like `__env` and then in the actual bundle code set it to `process.env` in your entry file. This is untested solution, but I believe it should work.

#### Option 2

Use localStorage and let your main script read variables from there upon initialization. You can set variables to localStorage manually or you can even let the server provide them if you have them in there. Developer would just open console and type something like `loadEnv('production')`, it would do XHR and store the result in the localStorage. Even with manual approach there is still an advantage that these doesn't need to hard-coded in html.

If manual doesn't sound good enough and server is a dead end too, you could just include all variables from all environments (if you have them somewhere) in the bundle and then use `switch` statement to choose correct ones based on some conditions (eg. localhost, production host).

---

Thinking about this, you are definitely out of scope of Browserify with your needs. It can make bundle for you, but if you don't want these information in the bundle, you are on your own.

Comment: Are you suggesting to create a file per environment? If so, that's not possible in my setup because there is no predetermined set of environments. Developers are able to create a new environment per feature, and set their own environment variables that I need reflected on the front-end (in React). Using `envify` isn't possible either, as I mentioned in the question, because we build the js once, store it on the CDN and then use it many times in different environments.

Comment: Ok, I think it's kinda bad having single bundle containing code for all environments, but if that suits you... If you really need it dynamic, I have updated answer.

Comment: That's funny. It's exactly what I'm curently doing. It is a hack though, so finding a clean solution was my main motivation for asking the question. It looks like there's no built-in way to set globals ahead of time without this hack.

Comment: Well you should maybe first ask how it is supposed to work. You want single bundle, so these variables cannot be included in there. Browser doesn't know anything like env variables so only way is to supply those from the outside. I've added Option 2 above if that looks "cleaner" to you.

Comment: Whoever voted down on this, I would like to hear why do you find it so useless.

Answer (score 1):

So I've decided it's the web server's job to insert the environment variables.  My scenario required different loggers per environment (e.g. 'local','test','prod').

code:

```
var express = require('express')
  , replace = require('replace');

...

var app = express();
var fileToReplace = <your browserified js here>;
replace({
  regex: 'ENV_ENVIRONMENT'
  , replacement: process.env.ENVIRONMENT
  , paths: [fileToReplace]
});

...

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

I hardcoded 'ENV_ENVIRONMENT', but you could create an object in your package.json and make it configurable.

This certainly works, and it makes sense because it's possibly the only server entry point you have.

Comment: I'd love an explanation for the downvote - or more importantly, a better solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had success writing to a json file first, then importing that json file into anywhere that needed to read the environment.

So in my gulp file:

```
import settings from './settings';
import fs from 'fs';
...
fs.writeFileSync('./settings.json', JSON.stringify(settings));
```

In the settings.js file:

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    console.log('Starting ' + process.env.NODE_ENV + ' environment...');
} else {
    console.log('No environment variable set.');
    process.exit();
}

export default (() => {
    let settings;

    switch(process.env.NODE_ENV) {
        case 'development':
            settings = {
                baseUrl: '...'
            };
            break;
        case 'production':
            settings = {
                baseUrl: 'some other url...'
            };
            break;
    }

    return settings;
})();
```

Then you can import the settings.json file in any other file and it will be static, but contain your current environment:

```
import settings from './settings.json';
...
console.log(settings.baseUrl);
```

I came here looking for a cleaner solution...good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I run into this problemn building isomorphic react apps. I use the following (ok, it's a little hacky) solution:

I assign the `env` to the `window` object, ofcourse I don't expose all `env` vars, only the ones that may be public (no secret keys of passwords and such).

```
// code...
const expose = ["ROOT_PATH", "ENDPOINT"];
const exposeEnv = expose.reduce(
    (exposeEnv, key) => Object.assign(exposeEnv, { [key]: env[key] }), {}
);
// code...
res.send(`<DOCTYPE html>
// html...
<script>window.env = ${JSON.stringify(exposeEnv)}</script>
// html...
`);
// code...
```

then, in my applications clients entry point (oh yeah you have to have a single entry point) I do this:

```
process.env = window.env;
```

YMMV AKA WFM!