# React and ReactDOM bundled by browserify bigger than react.min.js and react-dom.min.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, browserify

i'm following the [react getting started tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) and everything is fine.
Then I tried to understand how to import external package and so I started to use npm, browserify, watchify, and so on.
From the same tutorial there is a [section dedicated to package managers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/package-management.html). The first question is "Why in the tutorial they write

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

but later they still include raw files, as follow

```
<title>Hello React!</title>
<script src="build/react.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.js"></script>
```

rather than include only bundle.js coming out from browserify?
That's not clear to me.

I kind of ignored this. So my HTML is including ONLY the whole bundle

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

which is generated in this way

```
browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] index.js | uglifyjs > bundle.js
```

Inside my index.js file there are these requires

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var $ = require('jquery');
```

If I go and look at bundle.js size there is something I don't understand. Total size is 520KB. Too much only for a little example!
If I remove require("jquery") total size goes down to 388 KB, so jquery weighs 132KB, but if I download jquery.min.js the size is only 84KB.
If I remove require("react-dom") total size goes down to 70KB, it means that React DOM weighs 318KB, while react-dom.min.js is only 1KB!!

What's going on here?
I read about NODE_ENV var (honeslty i didn't understand how/where to change its value), try a couple of solutions, but file size remains the same.
But that'not the point.

react-dom.min.js is 1KB, react-dom.js is 2KB!
So it doesn't seem to be the production/develpment environment, or am i missing something?

Thanks to anyone who will help me to understand a little more.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540627/how-to-set-process-env-before-a-browserified-script-is-run

Comment: I saw that post. How can I merge this
`browserify index.js -t [ envify --DEBUG app:* --NODE_ENV production --FOO bar ] > bundle.js` with this
`browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] index.js | uglifyjs > bundle.js`
?

Comment: You're probably including the non-minified versions. You probably won't be able to match your size with your own minification, because each library probably has a specific optimized configuration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce Browserify bundle of react.min.js and react-dom.min.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286874/reduce-browserify-bundle-of-react-min-js-and-react-dom-min-js)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
browserify -t [ envify --NODE_ENV production babelify --presets [ react ] ] index.js | uglifyjs > bundle.js
```

Comment: I does not work.
I moved babel transform to package.json, and left envify transform inline beside browserify command. Now I got no errors (seems it works), but the file size remains the same, and i still can see the "Download the React DevTools for a better development experience" message in the developer bar. So i guess I am still in developer environment .

Comment: It does work, but you need to use the `-g` flag instead of `-t` to transform globally. Otherwise, it will only envify your code and not required modules.